# Can an Employer cancel training he has planned if I intend to leave the company?

Tags: employer-relations, law, france

Last year, my employer planned a training for me without asking me, it's a good training course so I didn't decline it.

There are few weeks, I informed my boss that I intended to leave the company but I didn't start any administrative process.

After that, I received a confirmation of the training's cancellation, the organization confirmed that the course was not delayed but that my employer has explicitly cancelled it.

My question is not about if my employe has reason to cancel it, he has it.

According to French's right of training and previous precisions, the decision of my employer is legal?

Comment: As you put it, it seems to be a legal question so you´ll have to find a lawyer. That said, I find it reasonable that your employer limits his investment into you, when you told him he may not get any return on it!

Comment: Why would your employer need your agreement to cancel the training? Is this training part of your job contract?

Comment: You state "I informed my boss that I though to leave the enterprise" - to clarify, have you talked to him about leaving the company, or have you resigned?  If the answer is yes to either, then the employer is well within his rights to cancel any training planned if you are not going to be working there much longer.

Comment: According to the French's right of training the employer have to train their employees. Here, I asked me if he can come back on his decision. I agree with you, it's not brainfull to invest on me if he knows that I want to go away

Comment: look at it this way, why would a company spend money to train someone who is leaving? It doesn't make sense. It would be a much better idea to cancel the training and send whoever replaces you.

Comment: More important statement would be, why would a company be required to train somebody that was leaving, or indicated they would be leaving.  It would be logical to conclude that their requirement to train you ended when you told your boss you would be leaving the company

Comment: @mickaelw If the legal requirement for training is one that HR in France should know, it may be on topic here, but you need more details in your question. E.g. For how long have you been there? What sort of training did they already provide you (maybe they fulfilled their obligation already)?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I already have near 7 hours and half this year and 2 days were cancelled (near 14 hours). Thank, I check your link

Comment: Is this a question out of simple curiosity or are you really considering forcing them to pay for this training if you're legally able to?

Answer (score 10):

I´ll answer this more in general. For the laws part, please seek legal advice!

Absent any other agreement, you normally rent your time to your employer in exchange for money. So in general, if it is nothing out of the order, you employer can decide what you should do with the time he paid for.

If he decides you should be learning new things, and he pays for it, he will do so because he wants you to do these things for him in the future. If you tell him that you will not be available to him in the future, there is no reason for him to pay for you learning!

So yes, the cancelled training is quite normal and reasonable. Probably legal also, in most jurisdictions.

Also a little advice: **Never talk to your employer about leaving, unless it is to actually hand in your notice!**

Comment: Agreed.  Training is seen as an investment for the business, more than benefitting the individual.  If the business sees no benefit for training you, they won't train you.

Comment: And this is why you do not tell your employer you might be leaving.

Comment: @Jerone: Just had the same Idea :)

Comment: @Sebastien DErrico: That is a completely different premise, that was not made by the OP. These agreements do also exist here in Germany, but usually only case by case for very special expensive training. Often you can negotiate, that your next employer will reimburse you for the damages you have to pay to the old employer. So you mostly are still better off with the training.

Comment: @Daniel, I take your advice! Maybe my post is not enough explicit. My question is not about if he has reason to cancel the training, he has it. But, is it legal in France, maybe it's different in another country. According to the French's right of training, there is an article which says: "the employer have to train its employees in order to maintain their ability to hold a job".

Comment: @mickaelw: Legal questions are off-topic on this site. You will not get an answer, instead you will get your question closed!

Comment: @mickaelw I'm by no means an expert in French labor law, but IMHO the cited sentence doesn't mean your employer has to  train your even, if you already handed in your notice.